Animation goes out of sync mid way
I have this animation. Both objects are rotating around the same axis (parented to empty), but the escape gear is also revolving around the same empty. The animation works fine till 600 frames when the fork overlaps the arms of the escape gear.
The fork is animated with a cycle modifier while the escape gear is using driver Euler.
Animation.gif




This sounds like more of a math problem than a Blender usage issue, unless the issue occurs suddenly, in which case you should include that in your video. Also, why is the empty needed for the demo? Remove it and see if the problem still occurs. Lastly, how many teeth does the escape gear have?

@TheLabCat There are 20 teeth. I hand animated the fork till two swings and put a cycle modifier to it. The empty is needed because I want both to keep rotating on their original axis but to make a rotation around the axis of the empty. So, I cannot remove that empty.

How many frames per cycle? I think there’s a strong chance there’s an extra frame in one of the loops, and they eventually get far enough out of sync to notice.

@TheLabCat THat's what I am trying to figure it out.

Are you sure your keyframes are correct ? For example if you expect a 50 frames cycle, do you have keyframes at frame 1 and 51 ? Not 1 and 50. Or maybe the other way around depending on your setup. I can't help more without access to your blend file (blender-exchange.com).

@Lutzi yes, my frame starts at 0 and 1 second ends at 23 for 24 fps. I can provide the file later when I no longer could figure it out.
